# Find Hostname in every file in directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I'm trying to find a way to read every file in a directory and return the hostname from each file.

I've gotten it to work with one file specified but now I'm trying to do it on an entire directory instead of a single file. So far i have the following but I get an error.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "Return first filename in the directory"
```

**Code:**

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(TEST_PATH):
    with open(filename) as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
            if match:
                print match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer. I had to append the filename and path. Is there a better way to do this? I'm sure there is, Any help would be appreciated.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(TEST_PATH):
    file_name = os.path.join(TEST_PATH, filename)
    with open(file_name, "r+") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
            if match:
                print match.group(1)
```